# Is there a way to automatically split large clusters that are greater than some maximum number of points?

Tags: python, gis, cluster-analysis, qgis, dbscan

I ran HDBSCAN on these coordinates and got some clusters but some are too large. HDBSCAN has a minimum cluster size parameter, but no maximum size. All I want is to intuitively divide larger clusters so that none are larger than a maximum cluster size. Essentially, something that creates the second plot below. I could rerun HDBSCAN on the cluster, but it isn't guaranteed to reduce the size. I can do k-means, but I'm using clustering on a shortest-path distance matrix, something that I don't think k-means can handle.

[image]

```
cl = gpd.read_file("cluster.gpkg")

df = pd.concat([cl.geometry.x, cl.geometry.y], axis = 1)

mins = 40
min_size = 400

clusterer = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size=min_size, min_samples=mins, allow_single_cluster=True) 
clusterer.fit(df.iloc[:, 0:2])
pd.Series(clusterer.labels_).value_counts()

df['cluster'] = clusterer.labels_
df['subcluster'] = np.nan

# Plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))

unique_labels = np.unique(clusterer.labels_)
noise_data = df[df['cluster'] == -1]


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(20,6)) # Create 1 row, 2 columns of plots

for label in unique_labels:
    subset = df[df['cluster'] == label]
    if label == -1:
        ax[0].scatter(subset[0], subset[1], label="Noise", color='gray', marker=".", alpha=0.3)
    else:
        ax[0].scatter(subset[0], subset[1], label=f'Cluster {label}', marker = ".", alpha=1)

ax[0].set_xlabel('Longitude')
ax[0].set_ylabel('Latitude')
ax[0].set_title('Clusters')
ax[0].legend()
```

Comment: Before looking at how to do it automatically, I think you should decide the criterion for splitting clusters. This question is probably best suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [PR](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan/pull/410) which adds to the source code this [parameter](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan/blob/61c16f2f3ef08bf5f1db5f609ef61f8a901ef500/hdbscan/hdbscan_.py#L519). They seem to be what you are after though they are hard to find, as noted in this [issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan/issues/559).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).